# Target that does not run in build .xml

Tags: java, ant

I have a build.xml file that contains some target tasks, but one of them does not run ?

do you guys have an idea about such case?

```
<target name="Minifying-Javascript_And_CSS_Files">
 <echo message="Minifying Javascript and CSS Files"/>
 <echo message="${env.WORKSPACE}/Resources/Minifying.sh"/>
  <exec executable="/bin/sh">
  <arg value="/c"/>
  <arg value="${env.WORKSPACE}/Resources/Minifying.sh"/>
  <arg value="-p"/>
  </exec>
```

Comment: Do you mean it errors out when you execute "ant Minifying-Javascript_and_CSS_Files", or are you executing it as a dependency from another target?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something wrong with your `exec` task.

```
<exec executable="/bin/sh" os="linux">
 <arg value="${env.WORKSPACE}/Resources/Minifying.sh"/>
 <arg value="-p"/>
</exec>
```

The `/c` looks like a prefix to execute a Windows CMD batch file:

```
<exec executable="CMD.EXE" os="windows">
 <arg value="/c"/>
 <arg value="${env.WORKSPACE}/Resources/Minifying.bat"/>
 <arg value="-p"/>
</exec>
```

Finally, make sure the `env.*` properties are actually setup

```
<property environment="env"/>
```